# Is seeing the whoopsie process running sufficient to conclude there are problems with one's OS?

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and often use top or htop to see which processes are currently running. I see the whoopsie process each and every time. Since I could not seem to find an answer elsewhere I thought I would ask, Is this indicative of a problem within my OS? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that process is running on all the Ubuntu systems. Unless you remove or disable it yourself it is there by default.

It should be included in `/etc/rc1.d/` where is it stopped and `/etc/rc[2-5].d` where it is started.